# check if username already exists in the database while user is entering values in PEGA

Tags: pega

check if username already exists in the database while user is entering values in that particular field(username)in PEGA?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please help us to help you. What isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a hint...

`Refresh` the `Section` on `Change` of the input field and apply an `Activity` which will do `Obj-Browse` in the table to check whether the User is present in the table or not.

If User is not present in table then set error message through `Page-Set-Message` method on the primary page.